# database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is to store all credentials to `config/secret.yml` and remove it from git.
Below configuration works as expected on Mac OS X, but on Windows 7 it raises error.

With config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_username %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_password %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project1_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: project1_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: project1_production
```

And config/secrets.yml:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: d48527bc8072d6d84ebd037c2324f474af315459b2c7912f6e1e3abfb616e0f92cdca194845d4235b287f032345312d3aec870d391b603dd8d1a888185f7c642
  database_username: postgres
  database_password: test-test

test:
  secret_key_base: d48527bc8072d6d84ebd037c2324f474af315459b2c7912f6e1e3abfb616e0f92cdca194845d4235b287f032345312d3aec870d391b603dd8d1a888185f7c642
  database_username: postgres
  database_password: test-test
```

`rails server` raises error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/connection_specification.rb:171:in `spec': database configuration d
oes not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/orm/act
ive_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Users/biske/mladizubinpotok/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in
`block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:293:
in `setup'
        from C:/Users/biske/mladizubinpotok/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `
<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine
.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine
.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine
.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine
.rb:615:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine
.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each
_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each
_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_
component_from'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_c
onnected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_
component_from'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_c
onnected_component'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_
component'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/biske/mladizubinpotok/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (re
quired)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Ruby version:

```
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

Rails version:

```
Rails 4.2.0
```

Any help with this?

Comment: Does postgres and the database exist on the windows machine?

Comment: @fatfrog, yes. If I use `username: postgres` instead `username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_username %>` it works.

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the username and use the secret for the password?  Or do you need to fill them both in?  Can you try hard coding in the username and password, and putting <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_username %> in your view and seeing if it returns your username?

Comment: @fatfrog It works only if both username and password are hardcoded. Yes, on view it prints properly.
To me it seems like parsing yaml file problem.

Comment: Note, it works on Mac OS X.
It doesn't work on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you make sure you have no extra white spaces?  I just don't understand why it would be parsed properly on OS X but not windows.

Comment: @fatfrog It's git cloned repository, it's same database.yml on both, so no extra whitespaces. I checked it twice.
I suspect on psych library which parses yaml files. Searched for solution few hours but without luck.
Obviously Rails on Windows sucks.

Comment: Yes, yes it does :)  - as a work around, I use ENV variables myself and the Figaro gem:  https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro - screencast on ENV variables: https://gorails.com/episodes/environment-variables